# Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Centrino Wireless-N 130 (rev 34) dropping connection

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have just started using Ubuntu for the first time. My wifi connection keeps dropping (it never did in Windows). I have read various threads, but people say it's wireless card specific and I haven't found one for this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and this card.

The problem is intermittent - yesterday it never dropped, today it started dropping every couple of minutes. If I click on the wireless icon, after it has disconnected, my router doesn't show. If I  click 'enable wifi' to disable it, and then click it again, my connection returns.

I had a look at syslog, and it was showing Reason 7.

The problem is worse when I am physically further away from the router.

Would appreciate any help,

Andrew

Comment: Same here, have you found a fix?

Comment: No, but it's only been happening every two or three hours recently, so it's liveable with. If I am watching a youtube video, even close to the router, it seems to drop every twenty minutes or so, surprisingly consistently.